# 600x1 px line not displaying Outlook 2013, 2016 and Win 10 mail client

Tags: html, html-email

I'm just trying to make a simple 600px wide line that scales responsively for e-amil, but I simply cannot make it display on Outlook 2013, Outlook 2016 on win 7 and Windows 10 E-mail.

The code looks like this, and the line I'm talking about is the line at the commentary "<--Horizontal line-->"

Right now i've made it an 600x1 PNG image, because it was even worse when I tried making it as an HTML line. Can anyone see what can cause this issue?

EDIT:
When I moved the HTML for the line out of the wrapping table, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The Height as a HTML Element takes the Pixel value without the px. So you should eighter put `height="1"` or in your style tag `height:1px;` or at best both. Also try not putting it as a gif, or will it be animated? In my experience gifs and outlook, allthough outlook will display the first frame, dont get along to nicely.

Comment: It isn't a gif, it's a PNG already, so that's not an issue.
I tried your suggestion, without any luck unfortunately

Comment: You could also write a mso exception. Tell me if the height doesn't work and you want to build the exception and need more help

Comment: The height didn't fix it, I can't believe this can cause so much trouble, I have other horizontal lines in the footer of this code, that works, but not if I copy them..

Comment: When I moved the HTML for the line out of the wrapping table, it worked.

Comment: Wow, ok. Then it might be that the wrapper was making the image less wide wich scaled the image down? Still odd! But good job testing and finding a solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML is the most efficient way to make a solid color or transparent spacer in email. Something like this should do the trick across all email clients, including Outlook and Win 10 mail.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" role="presentation" bgcolor="gray">
    <tr>
        <td height="1" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```